# Module not found: Can't resolve 'graphql'?

Tags: next.js, graphql, urql

My Next.js app worked fine yesterday but today it has an error like this:

```
error - ./node_modules/@urql/core/dist/ddbb86ae.mjs:1:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'graphql'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@urql/core/dist/urql-core.mjs
./node_modules/urql/dist/urql.es.js
./pages/_app.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

I have no idea what happened so I `git reset --hard` but the problem is still there.
Please help me fix it. I appreciate it.

_app.js:

```js
import { StateContext } from "../lib/context";
import { Provider, createClient } from "urql";

const client = createClient({ url: "http://localhost:1337/graphql" });

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <StateContext>
      <Provider value={client}>
        <Nav />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Provider>
    </StateContext>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope this solves your problem

```
npm install --save graphql ra-data-graphql
```

or

```
yarn add graphql ra-data-graphql
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, and it worked for me